# Estrutura de dados - expressões aritméticas

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Recentemente recebi o seguinte desafio na faculdade, porém estou com dificuldade de fazer

O desafio é:

> Identificar como um subconjunto de números de 1 a 1000 podem ser
>   escritos usando-se expressões aritméticas que tem apenas os seguintes
>   elementos:
>
> 5,    7,  (,  ),  +,  -   e   *.
>
> Por exemplo, abaixo estão representadas as expressões para os números de 30 a 35.
>   É importante notar que as expressões devem ser tão curtas quanto possível, pois seria simples demais achar apenas a expressão equivalente a 1 e depois soma-la tantas vezes quanto necessárias para se obter um numero. O numero de parênteses também deve ser o mínimo possível.
>   O grau de complicação de um número é a quantidade de vezes que 5 e 7 devem ser usados na expressão que corresponde ao numero.
>   Assim, 30 tem o grau de complicação 3, e 31 tem o grau de complicação 5. Devem-se montar expressões com o mínimo de grau de complicação possível.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> 30 = 5 * 7 – 5
>   31 = 7 – ( 5 * 5 ) + 7 * 7
>   32 = 7 + 5 * 5
>   33 = 5 * 7 + 5 – 7
>   34 = 7 + 5 * 5 – ( 5 – 7 )
>   35 = 5 * 7

Até o momento estou tentando dessa forma, porém não consigo chegar no resultado espero, não está gerando erro, porém o resultado de saída está longe de ser o que pede o exercício

```
package ex5e7;

//import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Expressoes {

    String[] expressoes = new String[1000];
    boolean[] preenchidos = new boolean[1000];

    public void preenchidos(boolean preencher) {
        if (preencher) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                preenchidos[i] = false;
            }
        } else {
            String pre = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                if (preenchidos[i]) {
                    pre += i + "\n";
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pre);
        }
    }

    public void multiplos() {
        int resultado = 5;
        boolean mil = false;
        expressoes[resultado] = "5 = 5";
        preenchidos[resultado] = true;
        while (!mil) {
            resultado *= 5;
            if (resultado <= 1000) {
                expressoes[resultado] = resultado + " = " + expressoes[resultado / 5].substring(expressoes[resultado / 5].indexOf("=") + 2) + "*5";
                preenchidos[resultado] = true;
            } else {
                mil = true;
            }
        }
        resultado = 7;
        mil = false;
        expressoes[resultado] = "7 = 7";
        preenchidos[resultado] = true;
        while (!mil) {
            resultado *= 7;
            if (resultado <= 1000) {
                expressoes[resultado] = resultado + " = " + expressoes[resultado / 7].substring(expressoes[resultado / 7].indexOf("=") + 2) + "*7";
                preenchidos[resultado] = true;
            } else {
                mil = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void somas() {
        int resultado = 10;
        boolean mil = false;
        expressoes[resultado] = "10 = 5+5";
        preenchidos[resultado] = true;
        /*while (!mil) {
            resultado += 5;
            if (resultado <= 1000) {
                expressoes[resultado] = resultado + " = " + expressoes[resultado - 5].substring(expressoes[resultado - 5].indexOf("=") + 2) + "+5";
                preenchidos[resultado] = true;
            } else {
                mil = true;
            }
        }*/
    }

    public void mulCincoSete() {
        boolean mil = false;
        int n1 = 125, n2 = 7;
        expressoes[n1 * n2] = "875 = 7*5*5*5";
        preenchidos[n1 * n2] = true;
        while (!mil) {            
            for (int i = n1 - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                if (preenchidos[i]) {
                    n1 = Integer.parseInt(expressoes[i].substring(0, expressoes[i].indexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }
            if (n1 * n2 <= 1000) {

            } else {
                mil = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /*public int[] multiplos(int num, int tamanho) {
        int[] multiplos = new int[tamanho];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            multiplos[i] = num * tamanho;
        }
        return multiplos;
    }

    public int[] soma(int tamanho) {
        int[] resultados = new int[(int) pow(2, tamanho)];
        int[] num = {5, 7};
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pow(2, tamanho); i++) {
            resultados[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pow(2, tamanho); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                resultados[i] += num[j];
            }
        }
        return resultados;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Seu problema é algo um tanto difícil e trabalhoso. Infelizmente, a implementação que você fez está bastante confusa e eu pessoalmente duvido que essa seja uma abordagem que possa resolver o problema. Eu acabaria implementando outra coisa do zero sem aproveitar nada do que você fez.

Comment: Há três critérios aí para minimizar a expressão: tamanho, número de parênteses e grau de complicação. Qual é a ordem deles? Por exemplo se eu tiver uma expressão menor, mas com mais parênteses, qual é melhor? Se eu tiver uma expressão com menos parênteses mas maior grau de complicação, qual é a melhor?

Comment: Eu não sei se essa é a intenção, mas existe uma [regra na matemática](https://www.somatematica.com.br/fundam/decomp.php) que todo número natural pode ser escrito por uma multiplicação de números primos. Se você descobrir a composição em primos dos números de 1 a 1000 pode verificar quais são esses números e descobrir se é possível obtê-los apenas com esses elementos que você tem. Se for possível você pode seguir com essa ideia para resolver o algoritmo. (é apenas uma ideia)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui fazer. O resultado é uma coisa monstruosa.

O código abaixo é dividido em várias partes:

- Análise léxica - Divide uma expressão numérica em uma sequência de tokens. Um token pode ser ou um número constituído por uma sequência de 5s e 7s ou então um dos símbolos `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(` ou `)`.
- Árvores sintáticas - Representado pela interface funcional `Operacao` e pelos métodos que retornam lambdas desse tipo. Responsável por fazer a interpretação de expressões sintaticamente bem formadas. Pode gerar um erro em caso de divisão por zero ou divisão não inteira.
- Análise sintática - Descobre a estrutura de uma expressão dada. A análise sintática é baseada em uma [linguagem livre de contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/132) e o analisador é [descendente recursivo LL-1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2044/132) com a seguinte gramática:

  - aditivo (símbolo inicial) → multiplicativo (cont_aditivo)*
  - cont_aditivo → (`+` | `-`) multiplicativo
  - multiplicativo → unário (cont_multiplicativo)*
  - cont_multiplicativo → (`*` | `/`) unário
  - unário → (`+` | `-`) parênteses
  - parênteses → `(` aditivo `)` | número
- Geração de strings de expressões aleatórias - Converte um número para uma sequência de símbolos formada por `5`, `7`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(` e `)`.
- Avaliação do número de parênteses e do grau de complicação das strings.
- Otimizador de expressões - procura a melhor expressão que gera o número desejado:

  - Procura por uma quantidade cada vez maior de caracteres, começando em 1 e indo até 12 e gerando por força bruta todas as sequências de strings com os símbolos mencionados no tamanho correspondente. Ele só procura uma string maior caso não tenha encontrado nenhuma menor que sirva.
  - As strings que servem são aquelas que podem ser compiladas e interpretadas sem gerar erros léxicos, sintáticos ou de interpretação e que o resultado da avaliação seja igual ao número procurado.
  - Ao encontrar uma string com um determinado tamanho, continua procurando por outra melhor com o mesmo tamanho. Se a nova string tiver o mesmo tamanho e menos parênteses que a anterior ou tiver o mesmo tamanho e número de parênteses mas menos complicação, testa ela ao compilar e interpretar.

O programa tenta otimizar todos os números de 0 a 100. O enunciado diz que é até 1000, mas como esse negócio roda na base da força bruta, então ele demora para terminar e não tive saco para esperar até ele resolver o 1000. O código do analisador sintático também podia ser melhor e um pouco mais organizado, mas assim deve estar bom o bastante.

Eis o código:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

/**
 * @author Victor Williams Stafusa da Silva
 */
public class Expressoes {

    private static class ExpressaoMalformadaException extends Exception {}

    private static class AvaliacaoExpressaoException extends Exception {}

    // Árvore sintática e interpretação:

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface Operacao {
        public int calcular() throws AvaliacaoExpressaoException;
    }

    private static Operacao soma(Operacao a, Operacao b) {
        return () -> a.calcular() + b.calcular();
    }

    private static Operacao sub(Operacao a, Operacao b) {
        return () -> a.calcular() - b.calcular();
    }

    private static Operacao mult(Operacao a, Operacao b) {
        return () -> a.calcular() * b.calcular();
    }

    private static Operacao div(Operacao a, Operacao b) {
        return () -> {
            int ac = a.calcular();
            int bc = b.calcular();
            if (bc == 0 || ac % bc != 0) throw new AvaliacaoExpressaoException();
            return ac / bc;
        };
    }

    private static Operacao op(String simbolo, Operacao a, Operacao b) {
        switch (simbolo) {
            case "+": return soma(a, b);
            case "-": return sub(a, b);
            case "*": return mult(a, b);
            case "/": return div(a, b);
            default: throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

    private static Operacao simples(int i) {
        return () -> i;
    }

    // Análise léxica:

    private static List<String> tokenize(String expressao)
            throws ExpressaoMalformadaException
    {
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>(expressao.length());
        StringBuilder proximoToken = new StringBuilder(expressao.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < expressao.length(); i++) {
            char c = expressao.charAt(i);
            if ("()+-*/".indexOf(c) != -1) {
                if (proximoToken.length() != 0) {
                    tokens.add(proximoToken.toString());
                    proximoToken = new StringBuilder(expressao.length() - i);
                }
                tokens.add(String.valueOf(c));
            } else if ("57".indexOf(c) != -1) {
                proximoToken.append(c);
            } else {
                throw new ExpressaoMalformadaException();
            }
        }
        if (proximoToken.length() != 0) tokens.add(proximoToken.toString());
        return tokens;
    }

    // Análise sintática:

    private static class Subexpressao {
        private final Operacao op;
        private final List<String> resto;

        public Subexpressao(Operacao op, List<String> resto) {
            this.op = op;
            this.resto = resto;
        }
    }

    private static class Continuacao {
        private final String simbolo;
        private final Operacao op;
        private final List<String> resto;

        public Continuacao(String simbolo, Operacao op, List<String> resto) {
            this.simbolo = simbolo;
            this.op = op;
            this.resto = resto;
        }
    }

    private static class Simbolo {
        private final String op;
        private final List<String> resto;

        public Simbolo(String op, List<String> resto) {
            this.op = op;
            this.resto = resto;
        }
    }

    private static Subexpressao parseAditivo(List<String> tokens) {
        Subexpressao a = parseMultiplicativo(tokens);
        if (a == null) return null;

        List<String> resto = a.resto;
        List<Continuacao> outros = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            Continuacao proximo = parseContinuacaoAditivo(resto);
            if (proximo == null) break;
            outros.add(proximo);
            resto = proximo.resto;
        }

        for (Continuacao c : outros) {
            a = new Subexpressao(op(c.simbolo, a.op, c.op), c.resto);
        }
        return a;
    }

    private static Continuacao parseContinuacaoAditivo(List<String> tokens) {
        Simbolo sinal = parseTerminal("+", tokens);
        if (sinal == null) sinal = parseTerminal("-", tokens);
        if (sinal == null) return null;

        Subexpressao b = parseMultiplicativo(sinal.resto);
        if (b == null) return null;

        return new Continuacao(sinal.op, b.op, b.resto);
    }

    private static Subexpressao parseMultiplicativo(List<String> tokens) {
        Subexpressao a = parseUnario(tokens);
        if (a == null) return null;

        List<String> resto = a.resto;
        List<Continuacao> outros = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            Continuacao proximo = parseContinuacaoMultiplicativo(resto);
            if (proximo == null) break;
            outros.add(proximo);
            resto = proximo.resto;
        }

        for (Continuacao c : outros) {
            a = new Subexpressao(op(c.simbolo, a.op, c.op), c.resto);
        }
        return a;
    }

    private static Continuacao parseContinuacaoMultiplicativo(List<String> tokens) {
        Simbolo sinal = parseTerminal("*", tokens);
        if (sinal == null) sinal = parseTerminal("/", tokens);
        if (sinal == null) return null;

        Subexpressao b = parseUnario(sinal.resto);
        if (b == null) return null;

        return new Continuacao(sinal.op, b.op, b.resto);
    }

    private static Subexpressao parseUnario(List<String> tokens) {
        Simbolo sinal = parseTerminal("+", tokens);
        if (sinal == null) sinal = parseTerminal("-", tokens);
        if (sinal == null) return parseParenteses(tokens);

        Subexpressao v = parseParenteses(sinal.resto);
        if (v == null) return null;

        return new Subexpressao(op(sinal.op, simples(0), v.op), v.resto);
    }

    private static Subexpressao parseParenteses(List<String> tokens) {
        Simbolo abre = parseTerminal("(", tokens);
        if (abre == null) return parseNum(tokens);

        Subexpressao dentro = parseAditivo(abre.resto);
        if (dentro == null) return null;

        Simbolo fecha = parseTerminal(")", dentro.resto);
        if (fecha == null) return null;

        return new Subexpressao(dentro.op, fecha.resto);
    }

    private static Subexpressao parseNum(List<String> tokens) {
        if (tokens.isEmpty()) return null;
        String first = tokens.get(0);
        int t;
        try {
            t = Integer.parseInt(first);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Subexpressao(simples(t), tokens.subList(1, tokens.size()));
    }

    private static Simbolo parseTerminal(String s, List<String> tokens) {
        if (tokens.isEmpty()) return null;
        String first = tokens.get(0);
        if (!s.equals(first)) return null;
        return new Simbolo(s, tokens.subList(1, tokens.size()));
    }

    private static Subexpressao analiseSintatica(List<String> tokens)
            throws ExpressaoMalformadaException
    {
        Subexpressao raiz = parseAditivo(tokens);
        if (raiz == null) throw new ExpressaoMalformadaException();
        if (!raiz.resto.isEmpty()) throw new ExpressaoMalformadaException();
        return raiz;
    }

    // Interpretador:

    private static int interpretar(String expressao)
            throws ExpressaoMalformadaException, AvaliacaoExpressaoException
    {
        return analiseSintatica(tokenize(expressao)).op.calcular();
    }

    // Gerador de expressões:

    private static final String SIMBOLOS = "57()+-*/";
    private static final int TAMANHO_SIMBOLOS = SIMBOLOS.length();

    private static String gerarExpressao(int chute, int tamanho) {
        char[] c = new char[tamanho];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            int r = chute % TAMANHO_SIMBOLOS;
            c[i] = SIMBOLOS.charAt(r);
            chute /= TAMANHO_SIMBOLOS;
        }
        return new String(c);
    }

    private static int complicacao(String x) {
        int comp = 0;
        for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '5' || c == '7') comp++;
        }
        return comp;
    }

    private static int contaPar(String x) {
        int comp = 0;
        for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '(' || c == ')') comp++;
        }
        return comp;
    }

    private static int pow(int base, int expoente) {
        return expoente == 0 ? 1 : base * pow(base, expoente - 1);
    }

    // Otimizador de expressões:

    private static String acharMelhorString(int valor) {
        String melhor = "";
        int menosComplicado = 999999;
        int menosParenteses = 999999;
        int menor = melhor.length();
        for (int tamanho = 1; tamanho < 12; tamanho++) {
            boolean achou = false;
            int max = pow(TAMANHO_SIMBOLOS, tamanho);
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                String g = gerarExpressao(i, tamanho);

                int par = contaPar(g);
                if (par > menosParenteses) continue;

                int complicado = complicacao(g);
                if (par == menosParenteses && complicado >= menosComplicado) continue;

                try {
                    if (valor == interpretar(g)) {
                        melhor = g;
                        menosComplicado = complicado;
                        menosParenteses = par;
                        System.out.println("Achei: " + valor + " = " + g);
                    }
                } catch (ExpressaoMalformadaException | AvaliacaoExpressaoException e) {
                    // Ignora e continua.
                }
            }
            if (!melhor.isEmpty()) return melhor;
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static Map<Integer, String> tabelar(int min, int max) {
        Map<Integer, String> tabela = new LinkedHashMap<>(max - min + 1);
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            tabela.put(i, acharMelhorString(i));
        }
        return tabela;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> tabela = tabelar(0, 100);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : tabela.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

A saída fica assim:

```
Achei: 0 = 5-5
Achei: 1 = 5/5
Achei: 2 = 7-5
Achei: 3 = 5-7+5
Achei: 4 = 5-5/5
Achei: 5 = 5
Achei: 6 = 5/5+5
Achei: 7 = 7
Achei: 8 = 7+5/5
Achei: 9 = 7+7-5
Achei: 10 = 5+5
Achei: 11 = 55/5
Achei: 12 = 7+5
Achei: 13 = 75-7-55
Achei: 13 = 7+5/5+5
Achei: 14 = 7+7
Achei: 15 = 75/5
Achei: 16 = 55/5+5
Achei: 17 = 7+5+5
Achei: 18 = 75-57
Achei: 18 = 5*5-7
Achei: 19 = 7+7+5
Achei: 20 = 75-55
Achei: 20 = 5*5-5
Achei: 21 = 7+7+7
Achei: 22 = 77-55
Achei: 23 = 5-57+75
Achei: 23 = 5*5-7+5
Achei: 24 = 7+7+5+5
Achei: 25 = 5*5
Achei: 26 = 75-7*7
Achei: 27 = 7+75-55
Achei: 27 = 7+5*5-5
Achei: 28 = 7*5-7
Achei: 29 = 7+77-55
Achei: 30 = 5*5+5
Achei: 31 = 775/5/5
Achei: 32 = 7+5*5
Achei: 33 = 7*5-7+5
Achei: 34 = 7*5-5/5
Achei: 35 = 7*5
Achei: 36 = 5/5+7*5
Achei: 37 = 7+5*5+5
Achei: 38 = 55-7-5-5
Achei: 39 = 7*7-5-5
Achei: 40 = 7*5+5
Achei: 41 = 55-7-7
Achei: 42 = 7+7*5
Achei: 43 = 55-7-5
Achei: 44 = 7*7-5
Achei: 45 = 55-5-5
Achei: 46 = 57-55/5
Achei: 47 = 57-5-5
Achei: 48 = 55-7
Achei: 49 = 7*7
Achei: 50 = 55-5
Achei: 51 = 7*7+7-5
Achei: 52 = 57-5
Achei: 53 = 5-7+55
Achei: 54 = 7*7+5
Achei: 55 = 55
Achei: 56 = 7*7+7
Achei: 57 = 57
Achei: 58 = 57+5/5
Achei: 59 = 7+57-5
Achei: 60 = 5+55
Achei: 61 = 75-7-7
Achei: 62 = 7+55
Achei: 63 = 75-7-5
Achei: 64 = 7+57
Achei: 65 = 5+5+55
Achei: 66 = 55/5+55
Achei: 67 = 7+5+55
Achei: 68 = 75-7
Achei: 69 = 7+7+55
Achei: 70 = 75-5
Achei: 71 = 7+7+57
Achei: 72 = 77-5
Achei: 73 = 5-7+75
Achei: 74 = 75-5/5
Achei: 75 = 75
Achei: 76 = 5/5+75
Achei: 77 = 77
Achei: 78 = 77+5/5
Achei: 79 = 7+77-5
Achei: 80 = 5+75
Achei: 81 = 5/5+5+75
Achei: 82 = 7+75
Achei: 83 = 7*5-7+55
Achei: 84 = 7+77
Achei: 85 = 5+5+75
Achei: 86 = 55/5+75
Achei: 87 = 7+5+75
Achei: 88 = 77+55/5
Achei: 89 = 7+7+75
Achei: 90 = 7*5+55
Achei: 91 = 7+7+77
Achei: 92 = 57+7*5
Achei: 93 = 75-57+75
Achei: 93 = 5*5-7+75
Achei: 94 = 7+7+5+75
Achei: 95 = 7*5+5+55
Achei: 96 = 755/5-55
Achei: 96 = 7+7+7+75
Achei: 97 = 7+7*5+55
Achei: 98 = 7*7+7*7
Achei: 99 = 7*7-5+55
Achei: 100 = 5*5+75
0: 5-5
1: 5/5
2: 7-5
3: 5-7+5
4: 5-5/5
5: 5
6: 5/5+5
7: 7
8: 7+5/5
9: 7+7-5
10: 5+5
11: 55/5
12: 7+5
13: 7+5/5+5
14: 7+7
15: 75/5
16: 55/5+5
17: 7+5+5
18: 5*5-7
19: 7+7+5
20: 5*5-5
21: 7+7+7
22: 77-55
23: 5*5-7+5
24: 7+7+5+5
25: 5*5
26: 75-7*7
27: 7+5*5-5
28: 7*5-7
29: 7+77-55
30: 5*5+5
31: 775/5/5
32: 7+5*5
33: 7*5-7+5
34: 7*5-5/5
35: 7*5
36: 5/5+7*5
37: 7+5*5+5
38: 55-7-5-5
39: 7*7-5-5
40: 7*5+5
41: 55-7-7
42: 7+7*5
43: 55-7-5
44: 7*7-5
45: 55-5-5
46: 57-55/5
47: 57-5-5
48: 55-7
49: 7*7
50: 55-5
51: 7*7+7-5
52: 57-5
53: 5-7+55
54: 7*7+5
55: 55
56: 7*7+7
57: 57
58: 57+5/5
59: 7+57-5
60: 5+55
61: 75-7-7
62: 7+55
63: 75-7-5
64: 7+57
65: 5+5+55
66: 55/5+55
67: 7+5+55
68: 75-7
69: 7+7+55
70: 75-5
71: 7+7+57
72: 77-5
73: 5-7+75
74: 75-5/5
75: 75
76: 5/5+75
77: 77
78: 77+5/5
79: 7+77-5
80: 5+75
81: 5/5+5+75
82: 7+75
83: 7*5-7+55
84: 7+77
85: 5+5+75
86: 55/5+75
87: 7+5+75
88: 77+55/5
89: 7+7+75
90: 7*5+55
91: 7+7+77
92: 57+7*5
93: 5*5-7+75
94: 7+7+5+75
95: 7*5+5+55
96: 7+7+7+75
97: 7+7*5+55
98: 7*7+7*7
99: 7*7-5+55
100: 5*5+75
```

Essas linhas que começam com "Achei" são para ver o que ele está fazendo. Interessante que dá para ver o otimizador funcionando, como nesse exemplo abaixo onde uma expressão foi encontrada para o 18 com 5 caracteres e grau de complicação 4, mas ao procurar por uma expressão melhor, uma com um grau de complicação 3 foi encontrada depois:

```
Achei: 18 = 75-57
Achei: 18 = 5*5-7
```

Curiosamente, nenhuma das expressões geradas até o 100 utilizam parênteses (eles são caros pois cada par de parênteses deixar as expressões mais longas em 2 caracteres). Inclusive, o seu exemplo dá isso:

> 31 = 7 – ( 5 * 5 ) + 7 * 7

Mas o programa achou isso:

> 31 = 775 / 5 / 5

E nesse caso aí, o grau de complicação é igual, mas o tamanho da expressão e o número de parênteses é menor.

Comment: Confesso que estou acompanhando essa pergunta, achei muito interessante e complexo. Como não domino Java estou tentando fazer em C#, achei esse [artigo](https://docgo.net/philosophy-of-money.html?utm_source=artigo-numeros-complicados) que é exatamente como resolver esse problema, mas como minha base matemática é negativa, está difícil. De todo modo, achei incrivelmente ****(censurada) sua solução. +1. obs: Ainda estou tentando fazer em C#. Depois de ler o artigo, acho que não pode usar 77 ou 55 etc.. :(

Comment: @Barbetta Evitar o 77, 55, 57, etc é fácil. Uma mudança pequena no método `tokenize` resolve isso.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer aqui, mas eu acho que não ficou boa, eu fiz manualmente as expressões de 1 a 10, depois eu combinou elas para dar os resultados seguintes, o problema é que seguindo o problema do artigo não dá o resultado esperado lá e é gambiarra kkk